# Is there a "get or default" way to access lists?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I like function get, where a default value can be supplied, but this work only on dictionary.

```
s=dict{}
s.get("Ann", 0)
```

I wrote somethin similar for list. Does this function already exist in Python3.4?

```
def get(s, ind):
    return len(s)>ind and s[ind] or 0
```

Comment: To be clear, you mean get by value, correct? Your proposed implementation is confusing.

Comment: why are you using `and s[ind] `?

Answer (score 2):

No, no such built-in method exists for `list`s. It is trivial to find out if a list index is valid, so no function is needed. You could just put the code in your function (or the even more readable `s[ind] if ind < len(s) else 0`) directly into the two or three places it's needed, and it would be perfectly understandable.

You can also use the fact that slicing a list always succeeds, take a one-item slice, make an iterator of that, and try to get the next value from the iterator. Then you can specify the default value on the `next()` call.

```
next(iter(s[ind:ind+1]), 0)
```

But this is going to be both slower and less clear than the `if` construction.

Of course, both your code and mine assume `ind` is always positive...

If you do want to write a function, you could make it a method of a `list` subclass.

Answer (score 0):

There is no methid like get for lists but you could use `itertools.islice` and `next` with a default value of 0:

```
from itertools import islice
def get(s, ind):
    return next(islice(s, ind, ind + 1), 0)
```

In your code using `and s[ind]` will return the default `0` if the value at `ind` is any falsey value like `0`, `None`, `False` etc.. which may not be what you want.

If you want to return a default for falsey values and to handle negative indexes you can use `abs`:

```
def get(s, ind):
    return s[ind] or 0 if len(s) > abs(ind) else 0
```